# Buffered Reader Outputting Runtime exec Commands

Tags: java, netbeans

Created this function to input unix commands and output the outputs of that unix command.  But, I am having trouble with the unix commands I use.  "ls" works to output the list of files, but if I do "ls -lart" it will output null.  Having trouble further debugging or why this doesn't work.  Code below.

```
private String[] unixCommand (String command, Boolean boolOutput) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Process run;
    int i = 0;
    String output = "";
    String[] finalOutput = new String[1000];
    sendToProcessView("Unix Command: " + command);
    run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    run.waitFor();
    sendToProcessView("In Unix Command");
    if (boolOutput == true){        
        sendToProcessView("In Output Mode of Unix Command");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getInputStream()));
        sendToProcessView("Passed Buffer Reader");
        while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            sendToProcessView("Output: " + output);
            finalOutput[i] = output;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return finalOutput;
}
```

Comment: Call `run.waitFor()` after you have consumed the command’s output, not before.

Comment: Found out that it will accept " ls " commands but wont take " ls Main* " commands with wildcard.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", myCommand });

Answer (score 1):

When interacting with the console, you should exec the console itself, and then use the Process input stream to send commands, eg (pseudocode - I'm not set up to test java code from my location, sorry)

```
sendToProcessView("Unix Command: " + command);
run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash");
PrintStream in = new PrintStream(run.getOutputStream());
in.println("ls -lart");
```

You can then shut the process down by sending "exit" and reading the results the way you were, or using a threaded listener, like [DataFetcher](https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java)

Comment: PrintStream gave a constructor error and yea I agree that exiting the process is best practice, but did not fix the null issue.

Comment: I have fixed the code snippet - it is now run.getOutputStream() (was getInputStream())

Comment: Sorry but not printing it out to the terminal.  Returning the value back from the function.